# What's the .egg folder in pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I am using pycharm/`python 3.8`. I am working on a branch let's call it: `Working_branch1`. I have some tests that I need to run, usually when I run them they test the version of my code: `code.py` located `\directory_name\code.py`. However since few days, every time I run these tests they are testing instead another version of my code of the same folder located in  `Lib\site-packages\directory_name-py3.8.egg\code.py`.
The tests are failing since it's an older version of the code.

Can someone please let me know what's this `.egg` directory and how can I force my tests to run on my actual code version instead ?

Comment: The tests are running on the version installed in your environment. Either uninstall it, or reinstall the updated version

Comment: @JoshFriedlander thank you :) can you perhaps write it as an answer, so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`site-packages` is where Python stores installed packages for a given environment. The tests are running on the version installed in your environment, which means you probably installed it at some point. Your options are either to uninstall it, or to reinstall the updated version.